# Python script executing SQL on Synology NAS

Tags: python, mysql, synology

I have currently on my PC a Python script which uses MySQLdb for executing Python script. I want my DS213+ to execute this script daily to fill my database.

The problem is, I cannot install MySQL-python because of the following error:

```
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Then I installed py26-mysql so that I may be able to alter my script for that. But I do not find any examples on how to use this one.

Searching for a few hours now for a solution, but I get the feeling that this won't be possible?

Comment: I think I will need to do the SQL part at the server side. Create a PHP script to do this and add my data via a POST request

Answer (score 0):

you can install a mysql connector from official mysql source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html. bye